# How to access all the different properties of SP List using powershell?

Tags: powershell, splist, script

How to access all the different properties of SP List using powershell?

I am only able to access "Title" property at the moment with $list.Title. I want to access its URL & versioning properties.

Also, it would be great to access all the other properties associated with the SP List.

Answer (score 0):

Following link has the list of all the properties that can be accessed via powershell script:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist_properties.aspx